# Opportunity Workflow running when Quote is Sync'd

Tags: workflow, quote, sync

Found a question [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gr75AAA) that went unanswered, but I'm having the same problem.

I have a workflow on Opportunity that is set to fire when "created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria". The Opportunity workflow works well, but has a problem when a related quote's "Start Sync" button is clicked. [image: button] (The criteria in the workflow is most definitely is not changing from false to true to trigger the workflow, so I have no idea why the workflow would fire. There do not appear to be any field updates or triggers that would cause this to refire.)

[image: criteria]

Comment: What is your criteria

Comment: Added photo to question for criteria.

Comment: It is most likely due to the `Current User` criteria being in there with the "subsequently meet criteria" being the trigger. I am going out on a limb here and saying that the current user: username will always be evaluated as being different. Try taking that out and see if it stops firing on every sync - Not sure about this though as I thought that Global variables did not affect the evaluation criteria but unless another WFR is changing a value and reevaluating it is worth a shot to check it

Comment: Taking out the Current User clause didn't work unfortunately. It still fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Salesforce's [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_rules_considerations.htm&language=en_US&type=0):

> Workflow rules are triggered when a standard or custom object in a master-detail relationship is re-parented, even if the object's evaluation criteria is set to Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria.

Apparently syncing quotes is re-parenting the Opportunity and therefore firing this regardless. I wish this was more clear.

Answer (score 0):

This result is quite obvious, when Quote is synced, `Synced Quote` field on the `Opportunity` is getting updated.

According to workflow rule, criteria you have defined `created, and any time it's edited to subsequently meet criteria`, that`s why it is getting satisfied to take action.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. Since the criteria isn't flagging a change and turning true. However if I had "created, and every time it's edited" selected then I would agree with you.

Comment: then whats the criteria?